# java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

Having a lot of trouble with this. It runs on Android Nougat and Marshmallow but on Lollipop it won't work(mainly, my fireTV). I'm getting the `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero` problem. Any ideas why is this crashing?

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
InputStream is = response.body().byteStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

long size = 0;
int red = 0;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
while ((red = bis.read(buf)) != -1) {
    size += red;
}
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

Log.d("ERROR CHECK", startTime + " " + endTime + " " + size);
double rate = (((size / 1024) / ((endTime - startTime) / 1000)) * 8); // THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS - A ZERO
                                                                        // SOMEWHERE.
Log.d("ERROR CHECK", "No Zeros....");
rate = Math.round(rate * 100.0) / 100.0;
String ratevalue;
if (rate > 1000)
    ratevalue = String.valueOf(rate / 1024).concat(" Mbps");
else
    ratevalue = String.valueOf(rate).concat(" Kbps");
if (is != null) {
    is.close();
}
if (bis != null) {
    bis.close();
}
Log.d("download", "download speed = " + ratevalue);
```

The line where I indicated with the comment is where the problem is. All the values in that line are populated, I checked in that Log.d line before it.

Answer (score 1):

If the `endTime - startTime` is less than `1000`, then the division operator will return `0`. Divide by `1000.0`

Comment: the difference is 908 .... that divided by 1000 is why im crashing. But why is it okay on other version of Android? Should I just use a bigger file to download ?

Comment: @JamesH at a guess, it takes longer on the other version.

Comment: Is it always less than 1000? Even on other versions?

Comment: Going to use a larger file to download. Thanks much fellas

Comment: But to be safe divide by 1000.0. what if somehow you get NASA like internet speed? What are you going to download then?

Answer (score 0):

When denominator becomes zero because of small difference, it crashes.
Use doubles, check the denominator and if zero, make some value (like 1 or 0.1) as below.

```
double den = (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0)) * 8.0 ;
if(den==0) den= 0.1;
double rate = (((size / 1024) / (den);
```

I think code like this will fix your crash.